# Column to aggregate values in another one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of values in a column, and I want another column to cluster these values to specific aggregates. How would I do this in Excel?

1. if a1 cell value between 0 and 5, then b1 = low
2. if a1 between 6 and 10 then b1 = medium
3. if a1 above 11 then b1 = high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table like in the screenshot and then use VLookup in cell B1 with the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$D$1:$E$3,2,TRUE)
```

With "True" as the last parameter, Excel will match the value that is equal or smaller than the lookup value. In the example, 4 is not found, so the next smallest is 0, so the value from that row will be returned.

[image]

You can also do this without a lookup table, using the formula

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,6,11},{"low","medium","high"})
```

A lookup table can be used by many formulas, though, and will be easier to maintain when the formula is used in different cells and the thresholds change.

Comment: nice, I did it with nested ifs, but this is far simpler. Many thanks.